Tradingview - Link highest point between two weeks

How do I only keep Week2 (yellow cirle) high to Week1 (blue circle) high lines(red cirle).
And skip other wrong connect line.
My code as below:
var float weekly_high_price = na
var int weekly_high_idx = na

is_new_week = timeframe.change("1W")

if (is_new_week)
weekly_high_price := high
weekly_high_idx := bar_index
else
if (high > weekly_high_price)
    weekly_high_price := high
    weekly_high_idx := bar_index
  
line.new(x1=weekly_high_idx[2], x2=weekly_high_idx[1], y1=weekly_high_price[2], y2=weekly_high_price[1], extend=extend.none,color = color.white, style = line.style_dotted)

Add the picture to explain what I want to do.
As the yellow arrow point to, link the highest point between two weeks.

